# Splitting in Java or using JSON

Tags: java, arrays, json, string, split

I want to split the following:

This is the JSON array I'm getting

```
[
    "Bus Stand",
    "Vazicherry",
    "Shavakottapalam",
    "Arattuvazhy",
    "Kallappura",
    "Kommady",
    "Thumpoly",
    "Poonkavu",
    "Pathirappally",
    "Valiya Kalavoor",
    "KSDP",
    "Bernad Junction",
    "Kalavoor"
]
```

I want to parse it as java array which includes something like this Bus Stand, Vazicherry, Shavakottapalam etc...

I tried it using simple split method in java, How can i split it using JSON object?

```
String products[] = x.getStops().split("[\"\\],\\[\"] ");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an instance of `org.json.JSONArray` with server response:

```
String serverResponse = "YOUR STRING";
JSONArray serverJsonArray = new JSONArray(serverResponse);
```

And then fill products list:

```
ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList<>(serverJsonArray.length());
for(int i = 0; i < serverJsonArray.length(); i++){
     products.add(serverJsonArray.getString(i));
}
```

---

Or if you absolutely want a String array:

```
String[] products = new String[serverJsonArray.length()];
for(int i = 0; i < serverJsonArray.length(); i++){
     products[i] = serverJsonArray.getString(i);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a JSONArray? I suggest using the json objects to get a string array out of this and then do with it whatever you want.
There are some ways to do that and there are a lot of examples out there.

Comment: link some of those examples and maybe provide an excerpt.

Comment: Instead of downvoting my answer which by the way was made before anything about json was mentioned in the question, you could have added something useful as well.